# Show that $[X,Y]$ has a single element.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I tried solving the problems from Munkres (Topology):

> Given spaces $X,Y$ let $[X,Y]$ denotes the homotopy classes of maps of $X$ into $Y.$
>
> (a) Let $Y=[0,1],$ show that for any set $X,$ the set $[X,Y]$ has a single element.
>
> (b) If $Y$ is path connected and $X=[0,1]$, show that $[X,Y]$ has a single element.

So precisely for both the cases I am expected to show any two continuous maps $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopic.

For (a) I have defined the homotopy as $G(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+t.g(x)$ and for (b) I have defined the homotopy as $F(x,t)=p_x(t)$ where $p_x$ is the path joinning $f(x)$ and $g(x).$

Unfortunately I could not show $G$ and $F$ are continuous. Please help.

Comment: (a) Given $f:X\to Y$ define $F(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)$ for $(x,t)\in X\times [0,1]$. This is continuous because multiplication $\cdot [0,1]\times[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is continuous and we are composing it with $(x,t)\to (f(x), 1-t)$, which is also continuous. This gives a homotopy from $f$ to the constant function $h(x)=0$.

Comment: (b) Given $f:X\to Y$ define $F(x,t)=f((1-t)x)$ for $(x,t)\in X\times [0,1]$. Similar to the one before, composing continuous functions, one of them the multiplication. Gives a homotopy from $f$ to the constant function $f(0)$.

Comment: No $g$, the constant function zero. The homotopy shows all functions are homotopic to a single one. Transitivity would take you from an $f$ to a $g$. In (b) path connectedness of $Y$ takes you from one constant function to another.

Comment: Ya of course. Nice, but aren't my $F,G$ continuous?

Comment: $G$ is, you can prove it using that multiplication and sum are continuous. $F$ is not well defined and potentially not continuous for some definitions. Ask yourself the questions 'which path joining $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? Do nearby points get nearby paths?'

Comment: Partial overlap with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912106/x-is-contractible-and-y-is-path-connected-then-x-y-has-a-single-point?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1587584/279515